# Evaluate variables' value in Kickstart file

Tags: variable, kickstart

I am trying to make a Kickstart install of a CentOS 7 VM interactive, by asking for user input in the %pre-install script, as described [here](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/interactive-pre-post-install-scripts-redhat-kickstart/).

So far I've managed to get user-entered values and store them in variables. However, how can these be used inside the Kickstart file? Variables aren't evaluated there i.e. `network --bootproto=static --device=eth0 --gateway=$MYGATEWAY --ip=$MYIPADDRESS` wouldn't work.